# Need image to automatically resize to browser window in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I created some pages to display a simple picture gallery, just the picture in the middle with next and back to click on either side of it. The picture sizes average about 800X1050, which fit great on my 1920X1200 monitor. What I needed was a way to automatically resize the picture to the browser height for use on smaller monitors, and I managed to get that to work after much searching on this site and others. I tested this on my wife's laptop and was happy with the results. However, when I tested it at work on our IE8 browsers (don't ask me why...), it doesn't work. Some of the people I will be sharing this gallery with will have to view it on our woefully outdated computers, so I've been trying the past couple of days to get it work and I can't. Here's the sample code I currently have for each of the gallery pages. There could very well be some unnecessary / redundant bits as I cobbled this together from many sources. Any help for this problem, and possibly even any improvements would be greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
<title>Picture Gallery</title>

<head>
<style>

.numbering {
 vertical-align: top;
           }

img {
 max-height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="silver">

<center>

<img src="10.png" class="numbering">

<a href="previous-picture.html"><img border="0" src="back.png"></a>

<img src="picture.jpg">

<a href="next-picture.html"><img border="0" src="next.png"></a>

<img src="spacer.png" class="numbering">

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by "it does not work" do you mean it doesnt scale proportionately? I dont think IE <= 8 had a proper renderer to scale images to a proper aspect ratio. you will need JS to make that happen in those browsers. [like this](http://wordpress.mfields.org/2011/scaling-images-in-ie8-with-css-max-width/)

Comment: I'll clarify. If I had nothing at all in relation to height or width, it would display a 800X1050 picture on a lower resolution monitor with only the top 2/3 or so showing. You have to scroll down to see all the pic (obviously, but I'm building an illustration :)) The code I posted above will squeeze the image so it all fits on my wife's laptop on her up-to-date IE browser. When I bring it up here at work on IE8, it displays only the top 2/3, having to scroll, as if it's completely ignoring the max-height:100%. That page you pointed me to was one of the pages I looked through with no success.

Comment: I thought I should add that the reason that page didn't help me was that I'm not sure where to put that code in my .html file. Also I have no idea what "I put this code in my theme’s footer.php file" means. So.. maybe it would help if I knew what to do with it?

Comment: what he is saying is you should put that code in the "footer" of your document which means insert the code at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag. you would need to wrap it in a script tag
<script type="text/javascript">
code goes here
</script>
</body> ...
the number in the code is the max width you want the image to scale up to. if you want the image to scale up to 1000 you would change his 615 to 1000.

Comment: that code would need to be added for every template you've created.

Answer (score 0):

As the Max-width property works in ie8, Use `width: inherit;` to make it work with pure CSS in IE8.

like this

```
img {
  width: inherit;  /* This makes the next two lines work in IE8. */
  max-width: 100%; /* Add !important if needed for the code to work. */
  height: auto;    /* Add !important if needed. for the code to work */
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll try these two suggestions tomorrow and report the results.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions, but neither of them worked. If I can't figure out anything after today, I'm going to conclude that it's impossible to scale images to browser height with IE8 and send out the gallery anyway. My co-workers will just have to deal with incorrectly formatted pages.

Comment: Harman, are you saying you have IE8 to test it with and you can get resizing to browser to work? Just to clarify, the code I posted works on the latest IE, but not on IE8. Maybe I'm not putting everything together in the right order. I would greatly appreciate it if you could post an entire working .html file so I could use it as a template.

Comment: What it comes down to is that no matter how I try to implement it, I cannot get max-height (or max-width for that matter) to work in IE8. Substitute a simple width or height statement and it works and scales the pic to that specific dimension. Of course, that solution would make the pic unnecessarily small for people with larger monitors.

Comment: I have realized that these days, it might be difficult to troubleshoot this IE8 problem, because who has IE8 any more (except my workplace! :< ).

So, secondary question. I use IE and Firefox on my computer, and my wife uses Chrome on her laptop. I could have sworn that my first attempt to do this worked on Firefox, but now I see it doesn't work on that or Chrome. So is there any reason the above coding won't work on those browsers, and any way to fix it?

Comment: I figured out how to get Firefox and Chrome to do what I need. I tried max-height: 95vh; and that makes it scale. I'm not sure what this does, but I assume it's some direct way to have it scale to browser dimensions instead of going through %.

Anyway, it still won't work in IE8 :(

Comment: I finally found a solution. Found out about /9;, so put that into the properties for the poster img like so: 
.poster {
        height:100%\9;
        max-height: 95vh;        
        vertical-align: middle;
        }

That way the posters will scale back to 100% length of the screen for the people at work, and will still frame properly on modern browsers. Here's the final product, and if you're a classic horror movie fan, you might get a kick out of my gallery.

http://www.landowonder.com/movie-posters/movie-10.html